# How to see VirtualBox fullscreen correctly?

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I just installed virtualbox, when i press HOST + F I see the window fullscreen but the OS still small. It seems doesnt not follow the fullscreen directive.

Someone coul dhelp me?

Thank you

KUbuntu 11.04

Comment: Try for (HOST + C)
By default host key for window in right Ctrl

Answer (score 5):

I think you have to set up guest OS's screen resolution to match your screen. Ie if the guest is Windows the right-click on desktop and select "Properties -> Settings" and select appropriate screen res using slider.

Comment: On top, there is a stupid thing to do it easy: just reducing then maximizing the VirtualBox window brings the inner window to the full size (provided previous description is matched)